# Angular Material Datatable not sorting data

Tags: angular

I got problem with my code.

The Material Datatable is generating fine, filter module also works fine, but sorting and pagination are not working.

My datasource is from my API.

The arrows for the shorting displayed, click on it work, but nothing change with my table.
Also pagination shows, but when I changed the number, nothing happend.

I honestly try everything, but with no result

Can you help me?

**HTML**

```
    <!-- begin:Table -->
        <div class="table-responsive angular-bootstrap-table">

            <div fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                <mat-form-field fxFlex="40%">
                    <input matInput type="text" (keyup)="doFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>

            <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="table table-head-custom table-vertical-center overflow-hidden">
                <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id.substring(0,4) + "..."}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ 'USER_MANAGEMENT.USERS.FIELDS.FIRST_NAME' | translate }} </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.firstName}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ 'USER_MANAGEMENT.USERS.FIELDS.LAST_NAME' | translate }} </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.lastName}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ 'USER_MANAGEMENT.USERS.FIELDS.EMAIL' | translate }} </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.email}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                   ........

                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
            </table>
            <mat-paginator [pageSize]="2" [pageSizeOptions]="[2, 4, 6, 10, 20]">
            </mat-paginator>

        </div>
        <!-- end: Table -->
```

**Component**

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    hasError: boolean;
    errorType: number;
    allUsers: UserModel;
    test: string;
    isLoaded = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    returnUrl: string;

    public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<UserModel>();
    public displayedColumns = ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'emailConfirmed', 'lockoutEnabled', 'actions'];

    @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;


    private unsubscribe: Subscription[] = [];

    constructor(
        private userService: UsersService,
        private modalService: NgbModal,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private snackBar: MatSnackBar
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.hasError = false;
        this.fetchUsers();
        this.returnUrl =
            this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'.toString()] || '/';
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    }

    public doFilter = (value: string) => {
        this.dataSource.filter = value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
    }

    fetchUsers() {
        this.userService.getAllUsers().subscribe(users => {
            this.allUsers = users;
            if (this.allUsers !== undefined) {
                this.isLoaded.next(true);
            }
            this.dataSource.data = users as UserModel[];
            this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
            this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you has your paginator under a *ngIf I imagine some tipical

```
<div *ngIf="this.dataSource.data" else loading>
   ..here your table..

   ..here your paginator...
</div>
<ng-template #loading>
loading data...
</ng-template>
```

When you give value to dataSource.data, the "paginator" is not here, so you need give a change to Angular to repaint the dataSource. You can use a simple setTimeout() SetTimeout only say to Angular: "hey, repaint the app with the date and, after, remember execute this another instructions) (*)

```
this.userService.getAllUsers().subscribe(users => {
    ...
    this.dataSource.data = users as UserModel[];
    setTimeout(()=>{
         this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
         this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    })
});
```

(*) you can use also [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the issue here :)